# How can I add a search function to a treeview?

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I want to display a row that matches the entry from all of my entry boxes into the treeview. [image] How can I get the values of the treeview and check if it matches the entry from one of the boxes and display the whole row. Here is my treeview code

```
tree = ttk.Treeview()
                books_data = pandas.read_csv("List of Books - Sheet1 (3).csv")
                df_column = books_data.columns.values
                print(len(df_column))
                print(df_column)
                tree["column"] = list(books_data.columns)
                tree["show"] = "headings"

                for column in tree['column']:
                    tree.heading(column,text=column)

                df_rows = books_data.to_numpy().tolist()
                for row in df_rows:
                    tree.insert("","end",values=row)
                tree.grid(column=0,row=4,columnspan=8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The short solution

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import sys
import pandas

# https://gist.githubusercontent.com/netj/8836201/raw/6f9306ad21398ea43cba4f7d537619d0e07d5ae3/iris.csv
df = pandas.read_csv('./iris.csv')
df.head()

class main_window:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        root.title("Treeview Search Example")
        
        # INITIALIZE TREEVIEW + SCROLLVIEW
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=list(df.columns.values), show='headings')
        self.tree.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/41880534/5210078
        vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
        vsb.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ns')
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
        
        for column in self.tree['column']:
            self.tree.heading(column,text=column)

        df_rows = df.to_numpy().tolist()
        for row in df_rows:
            self.tree.insert("","end",values=row)

        # ADD SEARCH BOXES
        search_frame = tk.Frame(root)
        search_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='nsew')
        tk.Label(search_frame, text="sepal.length:").grid(row=0, column=0)
        tk.Label(search_frame, text="sepal.width:").grid(row=0, column=2)
        tk.Label(search_frame, text="petal.length:").grid(row=0, column=4)
        tk.Label(search_frame, text="petal.width:").grid(row=0, column=6)
        tk.Label(search_frame, text="variety:").grid(row=0, column=8)
        
        # Add Search boxes
        self.sepal_length_ent = tk.Entry(search_frame)
        self.sepal_length_ent.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.sepal_width_ent = tk.Entry(search_frame)
        self.sepal_width_ent.grid(row=0, column=3)
        self.petal_length_ent = tk.Entry(search_frame)
        self.petal_length_ent.grid(row=0, column=5)
        self.petal_width_ent = tk.Entry(search_frame)
        self.petal_width_ent.grid(row=0, column=7)
        self.variety_ent = tk.Entry(search_frame)
        self.variety_ent.grid(row=0, column=9)
        
        tk.Button(search_frame, text="Search", command=self.search).grid(row=0, column=10)
        
    def search(self):
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/27068344/5210078
        self.tree.delete(*self.tree.get_children())
        build_query = ""
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/56157729/5210078
        if self.sepal_length_ent.get():
            build_query += f'& {self.sepal_length_ent.get()} == `sepal.length` '
        if self.sepal_width_ent.get():
            build_query += f'& {self.sepal_width_ent.get()} == `sepal.width` '
        if self.petal_length_ent.get():
            build_query += f'& {self.petal_length_ent.get()} == `petal.length` '
        if self.petal_width_ent.get():
            build_query += f'& {self.petal_width_ent.get()} == `petal.width` '
        if self.variety_ent.get():
            build_query += f'& "{self.variety_ent.get()}" in `variety`'
        if build_query:
            print(build_query)
            queried_df = df.query(build_query[1:])
        else:
            queried_df = df
            
        df_rows = queried_df.to_numpy().tolist()
        for row in df_rows:
            self.tree.insert("","end",values=row)
            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = tk.Tk()
    main_window(main)
    main.mainloop()
    sys.exit()
```

## The explanation of the solution

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import sys
import pandas
```

Obviously importing all the needed programs.

```py
# https://gist.githubusercontent.com/netj/8836201/raw/6f9306ad21398ea43cba4f7d537619d0e07d5ae3/iris.csv
df = pandas.read_csv('./iris.csv')
df.head()
```

Loading the csv dataset. I used the IRIS dataset because it is easily accessible.

Jump ahead to:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = tk.Tk()
    main_window(main)
    main.mainloop()
    sys.exit()
```

Here we load the `main_window` class into our main tkinter window (makes your code look neater)

The self-explanatory bit (added a ttk treeview with scrollbar):

```py
class main_window:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        root.title("Treeview Search Example")

        # INITIALIZE TREEVIEW + SCROLLVIEW
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=list(df.columns.values), show='headings')
        self.tree.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/41880534/5210078
        vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
        vsb.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ns')
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

        for column in self.tree['column']:
            self.tree.heading(column,text=column)

        df_rows = df.to_numpy().tolist()
        for row in df_rows:
            self.tree.insert("","end",values=row)

        # ADD SEARCH BOXES
        search_frame = tk.Frame(root)
        search_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='nsew')
        tk.Label(search_frame, text="sepal.length:").grid(row=0, column=0)
        tk.Label(search_frame, text="sepal.width:").grid(row=0, column=2)
        tk.Label(search_frame, text="petal.length:").grid(row=0, column=4)
        tk.Label(search_frame, text="petal.width:").grid(row=0, column=6)
        tk.Label(search_frame, text="variety:").grid(row=0, column=8)

        # Add Search boxes
        self.sepal_length_ent = tk.Entry(search_frame)
        self.sepal_length_ent.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.sepal_width_ent = tk.Entry(search_frame)
        self.sepal_width_ent.grid(row=0, column=3)
        self.petal_length_ent = tk.Entry(search_frame)
        self.petal_length_ent.grid(row=0, column=5)
        self.petal_width_ent = tk.Entry(search_frame)
        self.petal_width_ent.grid(row=0, column=7)
        self.variety_ent = tk.Entry(search_frame)
        self.variety_ent.grid(row=0, column=9)

        tk.Button(search_frame, text="Search", command=self.search).grid(row=0, column=10)
```

```py
    def search(self):
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/27068344/5210078
        self.tree.delete(*self.tree.get_children())
```

Delete all the rows in the table

```py
        build_query = ""
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/56157729/5210078
        if self.sepal_length_ent.get():
            build_query += f'& {self.sepal_length_ent.get()} == `sepal.length` '
        if self.sepal_width_ent.get():
            build_query += f'& {self.sepal_width_ent.get()} == `sepal.width` '
        if self.petal_length_ent.get():
            build_query += f'& {self.petal_length_ent.get()} == `petal.length` '
        if self.petal_width_ent.get():
            build_query += f'& {self.petal_width_ent.get()} == `petal.width` '
        if self.variety_ent.get():
            build_query += f'& "{self.variety_ent.get()}" in `variety`'
```

Build a search query. Use `==` for integers/floats and use `in` when searching inside strings. If you want to read more about queries, read [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html). If you wanted to do something wacky, like make one of your entries a "lower than" box for integers, you could even substitute in a `<` or `>`. It basically makes our life much easier here! Because we can do a query, based off a dynamically changing string!

```
        if build_query:
            print(build_query)
            queried_df = df.query(build_query[1:])
        else:
            queried_df = df
```

If there is no `build_query` (no inputs in entry boxes), just reload the table with the data from the `df`. (`if build_query:` is shorthand for `if build_query != '':`)
If there is query data, do a query with the query terms.

```py
        df_rows = queried_df.to_numpy().tolist()
        for row in df_rows:
            self.tree.insert("","end",values=row)
```

Reload the `treeview` with the data from the "new" queried df!

If you wanted a solution relate to your actual `csv` and interface, I'd recommend sharing an example of your `csv` and the gui design.

## What the solution became

```py
         def search():
                    # clear the tree of data
                    tree.delete(*tree.get_children())
                    entries = [
                    title_entry,
                    author_entry,
                    subject_category_entry,
                    publication_date_entry
                    ]
                    build_df = books_data
                    if entries[0].get():
                        build_df = build_df[build_df.TITLE.str.contains(entries[0].get())]
                    if entries[1].get():
                        build_df = build_df[build_df.AUTHOR.str.contains(entries[1].get())]
                    if entries[2].get():
                        build_df = build_df[build_df.SUBJECT_CATEGORY.str.contains(entries[2].get())]    
                    if entries[3].get():
                        build_df = build_df[build_df.PUBLICATION_DATE == (entries[3].get())]    
                        
                    df_rows = build_df.to_numpy().tolist()
                    for row in df_rows:
                        tree.insert("","end",values=row)
```

Comment: Hi, I'm having a ahard time understanding the build query part, how can I get the data from the treeview and check if the entry matches the data and display it. Can I contact you to show you the data frame im working with?

Comment: @Noahwaaa feel free to contact me via my email address (blackburnfjames@gmail.com)