# Get treeview row and put it into another treeview in another root

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I made a checkout function in my library management system. It aims to let the user choose books from the given treeview: [image: Treeview GUI] I aim to get the row of data that the user clicks on and pressed "add to cart" to another window with a treeview: [image: checkout page]. Only adding the specific row of books data that they chose from the main page. Here is my treeview code:

```
reserve_button = Button(text="RESERVE" ,fg=WHITE, bg=NAVY_BLUE, width=20, command=reserve)
                reserve_button.grid(column=5,row=5)
                checkout_button = Button(text="CHECKOUT", fg=WHITE,bg="#6DA5A9",width=20,command=checkout_page)
                checkout_button.grid(column=0,row=5,sticky="w")
                search_button = Button(text="SEARCH", fg=WHITE,bg="pink", width=20, command=search)
                search_button.grid(column=3,row=3)
                add_to_cart = Button(text="ADD TO CART", fg=WHITE,bg="#7E370C", width=20,command=add_to_cart_f)
                add_to_cart.grid(column=7, row=5,sticky="e")


                tree = ttk.Treeview()
                books_data = pandas.read_csv("List of Books - Sheet1 (3).csv")
                df_column = books_data.columns.values
                print(len(df_column))
                print(df_column)
                tree["column"] = list(books_data.columns)
                tree["show"] = "headings"
                vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical", command=tree.yview())
                vsb.grid(column=8, row=4, sticky="ns")
                tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

                for column in tree['column']:
                    tree.heading(column,text=column)

                df_rows = books_data.to_numpy().tolist()
                for row in df_rows:
                    tree.insert("","end",values=row)
                tree.grid(column=0,row=4,columnspan=8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The short answer

I created an example project that would use this:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import sys
from numpy import select
import pandas

# https://gist.githubusercontent.com/netj/8836201/raw/6f9306ad21398ea43cba4f7d537619d0e07d5ae3/iris.csv
df = pandas.read_csv('./booklist.csv')
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('.', '', regex=False)
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '_', regex=False)
df.head()

class main_window:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        root.title("Treeview Search Example")
        
        # Create DataFrame for this window
        self.build_df = df.copy()
        self.checkout_ids = []
        
        
        # INITIALIZE TREEVIEW + SCROLLVIEW
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=list(df.columns.values), show='headings')
        self.tree.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/41880534/5210078
        vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
        vsb.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ns')
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
        
        for column in self.tree['column']:
            self.tree.heading(column,text=column)

        df_rows = df.to_numpy().tolist()
        for row in df_rows:
            if row[4] != 0:
                self.tree.insert("","end",values=row)

        # ADD SEARCH BOXES
        search_frame = tk.Frame(root)
        search_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='nsew')
        tk.Label(search_frame, text="TITLE:").grid(row=0, column=0)
        tk.Label(search_frame, text="AUTHOR:").grid(row=0, column=2)
        tk.Label(search_frame, text="IDENTIFICATION NO:").grid(row=0, column=4)
        tk.Label(search_frame, text="SUBJECT CATEGORY:").grid(row=0, column=6)
        
        # Add Search boxes
        self.title_ent = tk.Entry(search_frame)
        self.title_ent.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.author_ent = tk.Entry(search_frame)
        self.author_ent.grid(row=0, column=3)
        self.identifaction_ent = tk.Entry(search_frame)
        self.identifaction_ent.grid(row=0, column=5)
        self.category_ent = tk.Entry(search_frame)
        self.category_ent.grid(row=0, column=7)
        
        tk.Button(search_frame, text="Search", command=self.search).grid(row=0, column=10)
        tk.Button(search_frame, text="Reseve", command=self.reserve).grid(row=0, column=11)
        
    def search(self):
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/27068344/5210078
        self.tree.delete(*self.tree.get_children())
        self.build_df = df.copy()
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/56157729/5210078
        entries = [
        self.title_ent,
        self.author_ent,
        self.identifaction_ent,
        self.category_ent
        ]
        if entries[0].get():
            self.build_df = self.build_df[self.build_df.TITLE.str.contains(entries[0].get())]
        if entries[1].get():
            self.build_df = self.build_df[self.build_df.AUTHOR.str.contains(entries[1].get())]
        if entries[2].get():
            self.build_df = self.build_df[self.build_df.SUBJECT_CATEGORY.str.contains(entries[2].get())]    
        if entries[3].get():
            self.build_df = self.build_df[self.build_df.PUBLICATION_DATE == (entries[3].get())]    
            
        df_rows = self.build_df.to_numpy().tolist()
        for row in df_rows:
            print(row)
            if row[4] != 0:
                self.tree.insert("","end",values=row)
            
    def reserve(self):
        selected = self.tree.item(self.tree.focus())
        if selected['values']:
            # get the id
            book_id = selected['values'][3]
            book_id_val = df.loc[df['IDENTIFICATION_NO'] == book_id, 'BOOK_ITEM'].to_numpy().tolist()[0] 
            if book_id_val < 1:
                return 0
            else:
                self.checkout_ids.append(book_id)
                df.loc[df['IDENTIFICATION_NO'] == book_id, 'BOOK_ITEM']  = book_id_val  - 1
                self.search()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = tk.Tk()
    main_window(main)
    main.mainloop()
    sys.exit()
```

Where `booklist.csv` looks like the following:

```
TITLE,AUTHOR,PUBLICATION DATE,IDENTIFICATION NO.,BOOK ITEM,SUBJECT CATEGORY
Book 1,Author 1,1923,001/geo003/1993,4,Awesome
Book 2,Author 2,1924,001/geo003/1994,5,Awesome
Book 3,Author 3,1925,001/geo003/1995,6,Awesome
Book 4,Author 4,1926,001/geo003/1996,7,Awesome
Book 5,Author 5,1927,001/geo003/1997,8,Awesome
Book 6,Author 6,1928,001/geo003/1998,9,Awesome
Book 7,Author 7,1929,001/geo003/1999,10,Awesome
Book 8,Author 8,1930,001/geo003/2000,11,Awesome
Book 9,Author 9,1931,001/geo003/2001,12,Awesome
Book 10,Author 10,1932,001/geo003/2002,13,Awesome
```

## The explanation

```py
df = pandas.read_csv('./booklist.csv')
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('.', '', regex=False)
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '_', regex=False)
```

Clean-up the `csv` file, so there are no spaces or `.` in column names (`pandas` really doesn't like them and they are not necessary)

```py
class main_window:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        root.title("Treeview Search Example")
        
        # Create DataFrame for this window
        self.build_df = df.copy()
        self.checkout_ids = []
```

Initialize a class `main_window` which contains the code you need. And create two variables `build_df` and `checkout_ids`, the `checkout_ids` will be a list containing your current "basket". The `build_df` holds a temporary copy of your `DataFrame (df)`, which can be filtered and moved around as you like, without effecting the original `DataFrame`.

```
# INITIALIZE TREEVIEW + SCROLLVIEW
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=list(df.columns.values), show='headings')
        self.tree.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/41880534/5210078
        vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
        vsb.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ns')
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
        
        for column in self.tree['column']:
            self.tree.heading(column,text=column)

        df_rows = df.to_numpy().tolist()
        for row in df_rows:
            if row[4] != 0:
                self.tree.insert("","end",values=row)

        # ADD SEARCH BOXES
        search_frame = tk.Frame(root)
        search_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='nsew')
        tk.Label(search_frame, text="TITLE:").grid(row=0, column=0)
        tk.Label(search_frame, text="AUTHOR:").grid(row=0, column=2)
        tk.Label(search_frame, text="IDENTIFICATION NO:").grid(row=0, column=4)
        tk.Label(search_frame, text="SUBJECT CATEGORY:").grid(row=0, column=6)
        
        # Add Search boxes
        self.title_ent = tk.Entry(search_frame)
        self.title_ent.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.author_ent = tk.Entry(search_frame)
        self.author_ent.grid(row=0, column=3)
        self.identifaction_ent = tk.Entry(search_frame)
        self.identifaction_ent.grid(row=0, column=5)
        self.category_ent = tk.Entry(search_frame)
        self.category_ent.grid(row=0, column=7)
        
        tk.Button(search_frame, text="Search", command=self.search).grid(row=0, column=10)
        tk.Button(search_frame, text="Reseve", command=self.reserve).grid(row=0, column=11)
```

Initialize the main UI, this holds things like your entry boxes. Importantly, the `if` statement: `if row[4] != 0:` is used because if there are no books available, there is no reason to display them!

```py
    def search(self):
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/27068344/5210078
        self.tree.delete(*self.tree.get_children())
        self.build_df = df.copy()
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/56157729/5210078
        entries = [
        self.title_ent,
        self.author_ent,
        self.identifaction_ent,
        self.category_ent
        ]
        if entries[0].get():
            self.build_df = self.build_df[self.build_df.TITLE.str.contains(entries[0].get())]
        if entries[1].get():
            self.build_df = self.build_df[self.build_df.AUTHOR.str.contains(entries[1].get())]
        if entries[2].get():
            self.build_df = self.build_df[self.build_df.SUBJECT_CATEGORY.str.contains(entries[2].get())]    
        if entries[3].get():
            self.build_df = self.build_df[self.build_df.PUBLICATION_DATE == (entries[3].get())]    
            
        df_rows = self.build_df.to_numpy().tolist()
        for row in df_rows:
            print(row)
            if row[4] != 0:
                self.tree.insert("","end",values=row)
```

The `search` system remains the same as the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70086490/5210078)! Other than the `if` statement functionality added as seen earlier!

##### The reserve function

```py
 def reserve(self):
        selected = self.tree.item(self.tree.focus())
        if selected['values']:
            # get the id
            book_id = selected['values'][3]
            book_id_val = df.loc[df['IDENTIFICATION_NO'] == book_id, 'BOOK_ITEM'].to_numpy().tolist()[0] 
            if book_id_val < 1:
                return 0
            else:
                self.checkout_ids.append(book_id)
                df.loc[df['IDENTIFICATION_NO'] == book_id, 'BOOK_ITEM']  = book_id_val  - 1
                self.search()
```

```py
selected = self.tree.item(self.tree.focus())
```

Gets the currently selected item from the `self.tree`

```py
if selected['values']:
```

If there is a selected item (stops errors when nothing is selected)

```py
book_id = selected['values'][3]
```

Takes the `book_id` (4th column) from the selected item and stores a copy of it.

```py
book_id_val = df.loc[df['IDENTIFICATION_NO'] == book_id, 'BOOK_ITEM'].to_numpy().tolist()[0]
```

Finds the book in the *original* `DataFrame` and get how many books there are of it!

```py
if book_id_val < 1:
   return 0
```

If there are no books available, don't do anything, (this is a fallback error-catcher because it isn't entirely necessary).

```py
self.checkout_ids.append(book_id)
df.loc[df['IDENTIFICATION_NO'] == book_id, 'BOOK_ITEM']  = book_id_val  - 1
self.search()
```

- Store a copy of the `id` into the `checkout_ids` list
- Decrease the number of available books by one
- Reload the treeview!